# Twilo unable to call the status call back url for SMS

Tags: twilio

We have exposed a url to Twilio to send the sms delivery status and it was working fine when we hosted our service in our own data center.
But we moved our services to aws ; Twilio is unable to call our service and it showing the below error
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200
please help

Answer (score 1):

make sure your Elastic IP Address is reachable using TCP/443 (you enabled this on your EC2 instance, correct) and your application supports both GET and POST methods. Check the Debugger (small bug icon in upper right corner of console) for any relevant error messages, otherwise the [error 11200 URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/11200) you provided has a lot of extra steps to check.

You should be able to reach your application via your web browser, for testing.

[Which IP addresses will Twilio's requests come from?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223183868-Which-IP-addresses-will-Twilio-s-requests-come-from-)

Comment: Thanks ..Issue was with our internal firewall